# Why Final is used in method parameters

Tags: java, android

When am coding android I came across the following thing

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.abstract_list_row_item, null);
        move.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                    // if btn is clcked then data is changed an we need to refresh framents
                    MainAppDataController.getInstance().setIsDataChanged(true);
                    callWhiteListDB = new CallWhiteListDB(_context);
                    callWhiteListDB.openToWrite();
                    callWhiteListDB.insert(allContacts.get(position).name, allContacts.get(position).number);
                    callWhiteListDB.close();

                    callBlackListDB = new CallBlackListDB(_context);
                    callBlackListDB.openToWrite();
                    callBlackListDB.deleteSingleItem(allContacts.get(position).dbId);
                    callBlackListDB.close();
                    populateList(position);
                    notifyListView(view);
                }
            });
        return convertView;
```

In the above example `getView()` method has parameters like int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent.My Observation was as soon as I start using position variable inside `onclick()`, Eclipse throws compilation error and asks make position as final. Why should I make it as final? AFAIK final is used for constants.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`final` is used in *method* parameters to make the *references* **unchangeable** after it is passed into the method. This is a specialized way of securing the passed parameters. so, the method receiving will not be able to re-initialize it with new object or value

Answer (score 5):

You are using `position` in your annonymous inner class. Hence it is required that position be final.

An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing scope that are not declared as `final` or effectively final.

The final modifier indicates that the value of this field cannot change.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: Why is it so?How final is related to anonymous inner class ?

Comment: @ARP OnClickListener is anonymous inner class.

Comment: @ARP check the link in my post under the topic **Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope, and Declaring and Accessing Members of the Anonymous Class**. check the second point.

Answer (score 1):

We use `final` keyword with method parameters in order to prevent the code inside the method to modify the value of that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

final makes your variable constant.

As your onclick method is going to get called after the finish of this function and your variable wont exist anymore so when you use a final variable it's constant value is passed inside onclick.

Answer (score 0):

- A java variable can be declared using the keyword final. Then the
  final variable can be assigned only once.
- A variable that is declared as final and not initialized is called a
  blank final variable. A blank final variable forces the constructors
  to initialise it.
- Java classes declared as final cannot be extended. Restricting
  inheritance!
- Methods declared as final cannot be overridden. In methods private is
  equal to final, but in variables it is not.
- final parameters – values of the parameters cannot be changed after
  initialization. Do a small java exercise to find out the implications
  of final parameters in method overriding.
- Java local classes can only reference local variables and parameters
  that are declared as final.
- A visible advantage of declaring a java variable as static final is,
  the compiled java class results in faster performance.

For more information read [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/final-variable-method-class-java.html)

also see [Use of final keyword in Java method performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150548/use-of-final-keyword-in-java-method-performance)

Answer (score 0):

Its because `getView` is called when your `listView` is inflating layout... And `onClick` is called when your `view (move)` is pressed... At that time when its onClick is triggered, the variable `position` in `getView` is destroyed already... By making it final you ensure that the value of `position` is preserved for later use